# How to login to facebook in android , using simplest method

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-login

I am building a facebook application in which i will sign in with facebook account, now i want to get/store the session variable, and to use it for further purposes like to get the basic, and other information of the user, where a session variable is necessary to pass it in request.
I am using this code for getting session variable but its not working.
 please refer me any tutorial or code which i will use for facebook sign in

```
   //Setting Face Book Id
     facebook = new Facebook(APP_ID);
     mAsyncRunner = new AsyncFacebookRunner(facebook);
     Session s=facebook.getSession();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Session.openActiveSession method. This is detailed in introduction for Facebook Android SDK  -  https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/getting-started

You will have to pass an implementation of an interface, with a callback method to openActiveSession - you can get the session object from there, and store it somewhere to be used later.

Example code below:

Private member variable belonging to activity:

```
private com.Facebook.Session fbSession;
```

Implementation of status callback interface:

```
private final class FacebookSessionStatusCallback implements Session.StatusCallback {
    @Override
    public void call(com.Facebook.Session session, com.Facebook.SessionState state, Exception exception) {
        if (session.isOpened()) {
            fbSession = session;
        }
    }
}
```

Here, I am opening an active session

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    Session.openActiveSession(this, true, new FacebookSessionStatusCallback());
}
```

Comment: i have putted this code in my application but it never open the session, although i have logged in my face book native app, what should i do now

Comment: Did you call Session.openActiveSession ? That should trigger a login dialog.  You can try debugging the app, and step through code line by line to see what the problem is. Also look at Logcat output.